# How can i calculate inside one input field

Tags: javascript, algorithm, forms, input

So i have a form and in this form i have a field that i want to make simple maths in it for example if i type 25+25 my input becomes automatically 50 for now it only works if i use an integer after the operation symbol so 25+25 will be (275) 25+2 and then it will add the 5.
Any idea how to fix this ?

```
<input type="text" name="input" size="16" id="answer" on keyup =" calc.input.value = eval(calc.input.value)">
```

Comment: I am sure there are many solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

He is an example how you may do it

```js
function myFunction() {
  const x = document.getElementById("answer");
  let value;
  let newValue;

  if (x.value.length === 1) {
    value = parseInt(x.value);
    newValue = parseInt(x.value);
  } else {
    value = parseInt(x.value.slice(0, -1));
    newValue = parseInt(x.value.slice(-1));
  }

  x.value = value + newValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="input" size="16" id="answer" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

I take the idea from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" name="input" size="16" id="answer" onkeyup=" this.value = eval(this.value)">
```

You could also use [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) for expression evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You have keyup event that is activating when a key is released, you may need to implement some delay before the action.

As an alternative you can do it with pressing Enter when expression is typed in the field by adding an eventListener to "Enter" key.

```js
const problem = document.querySelector("#problem");

problem.addEventListener('keypress', (key) => {
  if(key.key === 'Enter') {
    problem.value = eval(problem.value);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" size="30" id="problem" placeholder="Type a math problem and press enter">
```